# Libre Office Calc - problem with headers and row's numbering

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a problem of this type that when I open a specific file in Libre Office Calc (6.3.3.2) (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RwoBxTVUsPa5YLCAx_f65Nzonv1dQsRk  ) I do not see headers and row's numbering.

When you open a new document, everything works.

I know I can go to "View MENU" to enable this option. After enabling this option in this particular file and saving it and reopening it, this option is still disabled.

Do you know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to menu Tools -> Options -> in the Window which you will see on the left unfold "LibreOffice Calc", option "View", and then check "Headers columns/rows"

Remark: this is my qucik (by hand) translation from Polish > English